# How can a div get centered when i don't specify a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

When a design is fluid (there is no fixed width), how can  `wrapper` div using `margin:0 auto;` be centered?

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 767px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: If your question is "how can it get centered when I don't enter a width?" then I can answer that quickly: You have given a maximum and minimum. So it'll first check if the maximum value `1000px` is possible to set. If that is the case, it'll be `1000` and the other part of the screen will be filled with white space). As used `margin:0 auto` the div will be centered.

Comment: @JeroenE Thanks you got my question...Then if screen width be less than 1000px,there would be no white space

Comment: yes, that's the case.

Comment: Posted an answer with several examples to be complete.

Comment: Tell me the reason of downvote,i get banned from asking question because of reasons that i don't know

Comment: You won't get banned for it. I think someone down voted because of the unclear question. But not sure because I didn't down vote it. Maybe you can edit it and put the question in I provided in one of the reply's above. ;)

Comment: @JeroenE Thanks you help me a lot...Whenever i ask question i get -1 and now i was banned.I taught it is clear.If i edit ,can i get unbanned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183903/discussion-between-zahra19977-and-jeroene).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183904/discussion-between-zahra19977-and-jeroene).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max-width:1000px;` means: make a container that has a maximum with of `1000px`. If the page is larger (as an users uses a wider window) it'll fill the other part with white space.

The `min-width:767px` will then set the minimum. So if the users has a smaller window then `1000px` then the container doesn't fit. So it'll decrease it's size automatically to a minimum of (in this case) `767px`. If the users still has a smaller window, then a scrollbar will appear. The container will be set to `767px`.

If an user is loading the page in between the `max-width` and `min-width`, then it'll take the maximum width available. Please see the "To be more precise an example per case" section below for more information about this topic.

As you're using `margin:0 auto;` on this `#wrapper`. The `#wrapper` will be centered with no margin on top of bottom. So instead of the whitespace on the right side which will be set on default, now the white space will be shared on both: left and right side of the container.

I made an example with a lower width then your question in the example below to show that it'll become centered. This is all because of the combination of: `max-width` which is smaller then the window-size of the user (box below) and the `margin: 0 auto;` which will try to center the div when possible.

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:50px; /* added this as example */
  background:red; /* add this as example */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**To be more precise an example per case:**
Note (pre-condition): The cases below are when the div is as main-element in the page. So no other elements that have effect on the `#wrapper`-element. Just like the code examples in this post.

- User has a browser that has a size of `1100px` width: The `#wrapper` will have a width of `1000px` and there will be `50px` of whitepace left and `50px` of whitespace right. (see the above code example).
- User uses a browser that has a size of: `920px` width: The `#wrapper` will have width of `920px;` and there will be no whitespace on the left and right side.
- User uses a browser that has a size of: `600px` width: The `#wrapper` will have width of `767px;` and there will be no whitespace on the left and right side. Beside that the user will have a scrollbar on the bottom of it's page to be able to see the complete `#wrapper`. See the code example below for the scrollbar:

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 5000px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:50px; /* added this as example */
  background:red; /* add this as example */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 767px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the poster is not just using a div? Because then it would just work and `display:block` won't be necessary.

Comment: Yes you are right, if using div `display;block` won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Set the following properties on the parent element of the element you want to center

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;   // for horizontally center 
align-items: center;       // for vertically center
```